# How to insert all multiple values from list fields from Excel into database table

Tags: sql, excel, sql-server-2008, ssis, listbox

I am not sure if my question will be precise and understandable so I apologize in advance.

I have Excel 2013 file with rows which I should import into database table. Now, that would be easy but here is the catch: there are some multiple value fields (I think listbox fields but I am not sure, there are no properties or lists defined anywhere, those fields just have few values to choose from and little arrow box).

I need to break rows that have those multiple value fields into new row for EVERY value from the list. Every row in sheet has different values, and some rows don't have multiple values, those should be ignored.

Example:

```
column1      Column2      Column3
  1              2        multiple values: a, b or c
```

should be broken into 3 new rows

```
column1      Column2      Column3
   1             2          a
   1             2          b
   1             2          c
```

I don't know how to do this? Or at least how to import data like above (all multiple values, rest of the data just the same) into database using SSIS. Thank you for every tip you have!

Comment: Is Column3 literally `multiple values: a, b or c` What does it look like if there is only one value selected?

Comment: When you rreview the excel file in your Source, what does the data from this column look like a,b,c?

Comment: It looks like one value is selected, you can see other values when you click on the arrow button beside the cell. It's basically list of values with one value selected but I need them all to be presented, each one in different row.

Comment: I would use a script task and try to implement the logic that you need with C# (or VB). I think you cannot avoid to write some code.

Comment: So, I have to learn VB? Now I see, they used data validation for those fields.

Comment: yes you can avoid to write code, use split function or in 2016 there's inbuilt function string_Spilt() checkout its documentation